# When downloading MNIST, I can't get the "processed" folder

Tags: pytorch, mnist, torchvision, pytorch-dataloader

I am following a tutorial in here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IQpP_cH8rrA

I followed all the initial steps (except I am in VS not in Colab) but I stop pretty soon because when running:

```
torchvision.datasets.MNIST('./', download=True)
```

I get only the raw folder, not the processed one (which should contain training.pt and test.pt).

Can anybody help?

I am running on python 3.8.10, torch version 1.10.1, torchvision 0.11.2

PS: I found the same issue here https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/4685

should I really downgrade torchvision to 0.9.1 to have both folders?

if yes, how can I just downgrade torchvision from cmd, without uninstall torch and install everything back?

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution to this? I am encountering the same issue currently.

Comment: Still have the same issue. Tutorial did not really respond to comments so if anyone finds something would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I found this work around, downloading the data from tensorflow and then just switching the data types so you can follow along the tutorial again. hope this helps

```
import tensorflow as tf
import torch
import numpy as np


mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

print(x_train.shape)
images = torch.from_numpy(x_train)
ground_truth = torch.from_numpy(y_train)
print(images.shape)
print(ground_truth.shape)
```

`

This works in my notebook, hopefully it does for you too
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this answer will help anyone but this was my solution to it (after lots of trying and searching in the internet, I am not too experienced):
(I used anaconda prompt)

1. I created a virtual environment called "test" for python 3.6:
   conda create -n test python=3.6
   activate test
2. I installed the recommended torchvision version on it:
   pip install torchvision==0.9.1
3. I ran my program in the virtual environment:
   python yourprogram.py

I am sure this is not the best solution to exist but it worked for me and was very easy as it is just a few lines in anaconda prompt.

Answer (score 0):

you can download dataset images from this [link](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/novinnouri/mnist-dataset/data)